# Is there a list of mutually intelligible languages?

Tags: list-of-languages, mutual-intelligibility

Is there a list of languages which are mutually intelligible (i.e. a speaker of A can understand language B and [perhaps] vice versa)?

And would this beg the question of whether they really are separate "languages"?

Comment: No. There is no such list. There would be no way to tell different "dialects" or "languages" from others with the same or different names. Plus, nobody keeps track of who can understand whom (except the people concerned, of course). If you want to see something like this, perhaps [The Ethnologue](http://www.ethnologue.com/web.asp) is the place to start.

Comment: I see no reason to close this question, it has a clear answer (altho it is "no" in this case)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The proper term for what you're asking is [**Linguistic distance**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_distance). Sometimes it is also called **Lexical distance**, if only lexical units have been compared/measured.

Also, there is an article on Wikipedia called [Mutual intelligibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_intelligibility), and it has a nice list of mutually intelligible languages.

As noticed, there are several aspects by which linguistic distances (LD) between a certain pair of languages may differ. It may be orthography, morphology/lexicon, or phonetics.

The most intriguing fact is that **linguistic distances can be measured**.
Prof. [K. Tyshchenko](http://ukrainianweek.com/Culture/65223) has published his method of computing LD. I would specifically recommend his work, *Metatheory of Linguistics (Kyiv, 1999)* (Ukrainian, Russian), but I'm terribly sorry for being unable to find this work in English.

This is how the main diagram looks like:
[image: Linguistic Distances]
(image taken from [here](http://elms.wordpress.com/2008/03/04/lexical-distance-among-languages-of-europe/))

[Yet another version](https://alternativetransport.wordpress.com/2015/05/05/34/) of the same diagram created by a prominent blogger contains actual numbers of linguistic distances of even a larger set of languages:

[image: Linguistic Distances]

Also, the [Ukrainian version](http://www.bowfree.com/data/_Frequency%20dictionaries/lex-distances.htm) of the same diagram. Further explained [here](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/17401/1009).

---

> And would this beg the question of whether they really are separate "languages"?

An obvious answer is, there's a certain threshold in measured LD above which they can be called different languages, while below which they may be considered dialects. Also, it should be understood that considering a separate language may involve a political aspect, so the political desires may not completely correspond the linguistic reality.

Comment: Very interesting. Apparently there is such a list, and I stand corrected. However, I wouldn't say it's widely accepted, and without details of how the "distance" is calculated, I can't comment on its veracity. It does seem to involve borrowings between unrelated but neighboring languages -- I note that Estonian is "closer" to Latvian than to Hungarian, and that Romanian appears to be equidistant between French and Albanian. My feeling, though, for whatever it's worth, is that the Romance languages aren't as mutually intelligble as the Slavic ones, since they're been split up longer.

Comment: Excellent... wish I could upvote more than once... the only thing I can add is that I found this key useful for deciphering some of the 2 and 3 letter abbreviations in the diagram ... http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php

Comment: @jlawler Of course, such calculation is very subjective: various dictionaries may be used to compute Levenshtein distances; pronunciation recording may be done in various areas of the country and involve high/low-educated respondents, minor nationalities, etc. Finally, you may assign different coefficients toward written/spoken aspects of the language, and so on. I'm sorry for my inability to find an English translation of the work referenced. If I find it, I will certainly update my post.

Comment: Dammit where's Armenian? That's a pretty important Indo-European outlier. Persian is more important but then they'd have to also bring in a whole slew of languages it's related to, while Armenian has no known close relatives.

Comment: @hippietrail It must be due to a large linguistic distance, I guess.

Comment: Armenian has Hemshin and so on.

Comment: For me the problem here is that intelligibility must be represented as a directed graph - it's not always exactly mutual.  Often that is because speakers of variant or language A are much more exposed to B than vice versa, and thus know it passively.  The question then becomes how to remove "the real world", and whether it's even desirable to remove it.  It will depend on the application.

Comment: There are also extreme examples line verlan or satrovacki, where the base language is the same, but the *initial* intelligibility is low.  I think it is actually true of many dialects, which work more like cryptolects.  The point being, that the question "How much do you understand on day 0?" is not linearly correlated with "How many days do you need to understand x%?"

Comment: And, pardon, one more addendum: some people are just more practised at and open "stretching their ears", because they live in a dialect continuum, or a place with many foreigners etc.  People with very little exposure to dialects, foreign or similar languages and need to understand them tend to block out quickly any signal that is far off.

Comment: @A.M.Bittlingmayer, good point, thanks, but in my understanding, Tyshchenko's works are *not* about people's acquisition or perception of languages. Instead, it is an attempt to build a methodology of arguably objective, measurable calculation LD as intrinsic characteristic of languages itself. However, yes; as I said in comment above, it can't be 100% objective, since it uses some human-dependent factors (like pronunciation). Does it make sense?

Comment: Makes sense.  Of course we prefer objective numbers, but for some applications the subjective factors are in fact valuable data.  (The OP's question was about "speakers", but he did not say for what application.)

Comment: I disagree, 'Linguistic distance' is *not* the 'proper term' in this case; the proper term is 'mutual intelligibility'. In my experience the term 'linguistic distance' is used more in historical linguistics when talking about the branching and divergence of family trees, not in assessing mutual intelligibility. It's also used in language learning but there it's not about intelligibility, but about the differing rates at which languages (which are all non-mutually intelligible with the learners language) can be learned, quite a different thing.

Answer (score 11):

In terms of the largest list of mutually comprehenstible languages, [Ethnologue](http://www.ethnologue.com/) is probably your best bet in terms of the number of languages that are listed and compared. For many languages it lists other languages which share intelligibility and lexical similarity. This is discussed in more (but still possibly insufficient detail) on the [website](http://www.ethnologue.com/ethno_docs/introduction.asp).

There was a question on quantifying mutual intelligibility a while ago, in which I pointed to [Blair's lexical similarity quantification](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/2226/how-can-mutual-intelligibility-be-measured/2691#2691) as one way of assessing mutual intelligibility based on lexical similarity.

Comment: Ethnologue is biased towards splitting rather than lumping; see how they treat Italy, for example. But then again, bias is inevitable in this kind of activity.

Answer (score 5):

[This work](http://www.degruyter.com/view/books/9783110305258/9783110305258.507/9783110305258.507.xml) (H. Wettig et al., Information-theoretic modeling of etymological sound change) presents a measure of language distance based on the amount of sound changes between cognates in the languages compared.

It produces nice results, altho' it does not account for vocabulary replacement rates. (Maybe one can assume that sound changes and vocabulary replacement are proportional in a first approximation).

Answer (score -5):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_intelligibility

This is a very interesting and detailed list. Another great reference site with spoken samples is http://www.omniglot.com

Comment: -1: this post adds nothing to what previous answers have said. Also, we prefer answers that, besides of containing links, explain why they correctly and completely answer the original question.

Comment: The original post was from over 5 years ago. I was trying to help. 
 Not everyone wants a detailed explanation. There was an question, and I provided a possible answer and included references.  That's not good enough? My intention was for it to be brief.  Its self-explanatory, yet helpful.. If you don't like it because you don't think its "lengthy" enough, remove the post. Look at omniglot.com and the list of mutually intelligible languages along with a map of a dispersion region or distribution map it is helpful. My post adds to the previous comments in that it aids the distribution map

Comment: Some of the previous posts are factual, some opinion. Again, I was only trying to be helpful, and it seems a little silly to take the time to respond in the manner you did.  Its a bit rude and over-critical. Thanks for your time.

Comment: We appreciate your effort and we are looking forward to see your further posts. However, Stack Exchange is all about **quality Q&A**. So yes, well-elaborated answers are the keystone of the entire SE network. This is indeed because of the nature of the site, not because my answer is there. :-) Half-baked posts, on the other hand, only lead to further questions, denials, and idle chit-chatting. Please get yourself familiar with [answer] and [faq] to make sure your posts get appreciated by the community. And please don't get offended by the criticism.

Comment: P.S. If your answer appears to be too long, it is easy to mitigate with a short 2-3 paragraphs-long summary written on the top of the answer and then expanding it below.