# Worldwide map or data for linguistic distance?

Tags: comparative-linguistics

I came upon an excellent graphical representation of the linguistic distance between a number of European languages. I'm looking for a similar *worldwide* map of currently spoken languages. Or at least the raw data. Even if it's not truly worldwide, but just wider than the one presented here, I'd still be interested in it.

[image]

Comment: You use the term 'linguistic difference' but the legend on the graphic says 'lexical distance'. These would seem to imply very different things, why the difference in terms?

Comment: Ok, judging by comments at [Etymologikon](https://elms.wordpress.com/2008/03/04/lexical-distance-among-languages-of-europe/) and [LanguageHat](http://languagehat.com/lexical-distance-among-the-languages-of-europe/) it's clear this map does *not* represent 'linguistic distance' but 'lexical distance'. It's also not clear what list/s it's based on, perhaps Swadesh? It also seems not to distinguish borrowings from inheritances so it simply shows present-day lexical similarity.

Comment: @GastonÜmlaut Both concepts are new to me. Could you explain the diffrrence between the two?

Comment: I don't know what 'linguistic distance' would be, but from the provided answer it seems its being assumed to be some measure of overall distance between two languages in terms of their lexical inventory, their morphology, syntax, etc. Anyway, the graphic doesn't use the term 'linguistic distance'.

Comment: While 'lexical distance' is also a term I hadn't heard before, it's fairly clear what it means. The source of that map indicates it's comparing lists of words from two (or more) languages and counting how many are similar forms with similar meanings. If so it includes some cognates (i.e. those whose form and meaning are still similar), borrowings, false cognates (i.e. coincidences), etc so it seems a pretty useless measure altho it might have relevance for language learning. If someone could read Tyshchenko's article (in Russian) they might be able to clear this up.

Comment: Is there any chance of updating these with Cornish and Manx on the map? I understand that they may not have many speakers but if you're putting Asturian on there, at least pay heed to the two *living* Celtic languages that have been missed out; just a couple of tiny dots would be enough...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

@Fiksdal, I am the author of this of [this version](http://alternativetransport.wordpress.com/2015/05/05/34/),

[image: https://alternativetransport.files.wordpress.com/2015/05/lexical-distance-among-the-languages-of-europe-2-1-mid-size.png]

which is based off of Tyschenko's work, see [here](https://alternativetransport.wordpress.com/2015/05/04/how-much-does-language-change-when-it-travels/)

Since translating Tyschenko's map, I have spent a lot of time trying to figure out how the original list was made. Not much of Tyschenkos work is online and the best content is in Ukrainian or Russian. I also tried reaching out to the University in Kiev and Linguistics Department there, with no success. And I have limited access to any paper copies of his research.

But I think I have a pretty good idea of how the data was obtained.  These maps basically show the [Levenshtein distances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) lexical distance or something similar for a list of common words.  Now this list could be the [**Swadesh № 100** or **№ 207 list**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swadesh_list) with counting duplicate letter shifts in different words as one LD, or it could be [**Dolgopolsky № 15 list**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dolgopolsky_list) or a **Swadesh–Yakhontov № 35 list** and just brutally counting Levenshtein LDs on those lists.  Or Tyschenko's could have his own list of words and methods to calculate the lexical distance.  In one paper a master matrix is described with all of the lexical distance calculations and that each where calculated, but which exact method and a list of which words is not included.

I experimented with a couple of lists and methods my self and I come fairly close to the original matrix. Working on programming it automatically (if you have same word list from different languages) so it gives you a matrix over several languages and this is a test on Germanic languages.

```
|En|Sc|Du|Af|Ls|Li|Wf|Sf|Nf|Lu|Ge|Yi|Da|Sw|Fa|Ic|Nb|Nn|Sr
|00|13|29|30|30|28|26|26|32|40|33|34|39|37|38|42|38|36|37 English
|13|00|33|31|34|31|26|30|33|40|36|39|42|37|42|44|41|42|36 Scotts
|29|33|00|07|15|15|28|26|25|35|29|33|38|33|37|37|39|37|41 Dutch
|30|31|07|00|17|19|30|25|23|34|31|34|34|31|36|37|35|33|40 Afrikaans
|30|34|15|17|00|22|30|24|21|36|24|30|38|34|37|37|37|32|40 Low Saxon
|28|31|15|19|22|00|28|31|30|33|28|34|37|34|40|39|38|38|44 Limburgs
|26|26|28|30|30|28|00|26|27|39|33|38|42|37|39|43|42|41|40 West Frisian
|26|30|26|25|24|31|26|00|29|41|32|32|40|37|43|45|39|36|43 Saterland Frisian
|32|33|25|23|21|30|27|29|00|41|36|37|37|36|38|37|37|34|39 North Frisian
|40|40|35|34|36|33|39|41|41|00|27|40|45|42|50|51|45|45|51 Luxembourgish
|33|36|29|31|24|28|33|32|36|27|00|30|39|34|42|40|38|37|45 German
|34|39|33|34|30|34|38|32|37|40|30|00|38|34|36|36|36|36|42 Yiddish
|39|42|38|34|38|37|42|40|37|45|39|38|00|19|24|27|04|18|42 Danish
|37|37|33|31|34|34|37|37|36|42|34|34|19|00|28|28|20|19|39 Swedish
|38|42|37|36|37|40|39|43|38|50|42|36|24|28|00|10|21|20|44 Faroese
|42|44|37|37|37|39|43|45|37|51|40|36|27|28|10|00|25|20|43 Icelandic
|38|41|39|35|37|38|42|39|37|45|38|36|04|20|21|25|00|15|41 Norwegian (bokmål)
|36|42|37|33|32|38|41|36|34|45|37|36|18|19|20|20|15|00|38 Norwegian (nynorsk)
|37|36|41|40|40|44|40|43|39|51|45|42|42|39|44|43|41|38|00 Sranan
```

just to compare Swedish, I get 19 (Tyschenko got 21) to Danish, 28 (26) to Icelandic, 19 (16) to Norwegian (bokmål)

by German I get, 33 (49) to English, 29 (25) to Dutch, 30 (41) to Danish

My method and list does not match up to Tyschenko's but at times I am pretty close. So, yeah a *worldwide* version of this is possible, have to have the *raw data* from the languages (word lists) and I have to define a method and work on a program that could analyse the lists (and then go through the results to check them manually)

Comment: thanks, will add the links I wanted to. Work progress updates I will post on the blog.

Comment: AlternativeTransport Great! :)

Comment: Hello @AlternativeTransport and welcome to Linguistics.SE! Great to see you here.

Comment: @AlternativeTransport Very interesting, could you post a link to your code and sources of words?

Comment: @Matthias Schreiber, well the original intention was to add some missing languages to Tyschenkos work (Luxembourgish, Bavarian, Allemanic, Turkic languages, Semitic languages), so I was trying to get Tyschenkos exact method and word list.  Right now I am fiddling around with different methods and word lists.

Comment: To Methods:
I don't really think that Levenshtein Distance does lexical languages distances justice.  Lets say you determine the lexical distance from PHOTOGRAPH to FOTOGRAF. According to Levenshtein the lexical distance is 4, so 2 times P --> F and 2 times removing H.  But you could argue that since it is the same replacement and change it could be 2.  Or even only 1 lexical/linguistic distance. A different 10 letter word with 4 different changes is much harder to understand when reading.
Or with Umlaut ÜÖÄÅÜ, should it really count as 2 LD, AE --> Ä?

Comment: To Word Lists:
Lots of Synanoyms, 
should belch, throw up, puke or vomit be on the English Swadesh list? Should braken, overgeven, kotsen, spugen or blazen be included by Dutch? Erbrechen, speiben, kotzen or übergeben by German?  What do I do with Cognates whos meanings have changed, Meer and Sea, See and Lake? The lexical distance between אָזערע (ozere) and sea?

Comment: So, to code and sources of words, got nothing finished yet, but I intend to share it so that hopefully other people from other languages can DIY their own lexical distance.

Comment: Well, I would really like that. I think I would loose it out of my focus, so can you write me an email at mat@boar.bar? Would be great! :)

Comment: This is very fascinating work and a further project to create a similar worldwide map could easily win grants if the application was well formulated. I hope you and other linguists manage to continue this work and come up with such a map. Regarding the program to use, R has several packages for calculating lexical distances (e.g. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringdist/index.html).

Comment: Thank you for the tips and the compliment. This visualization is something I am doing in my spare time, it would be nice to have a team and funding. Is there a package in R that can find a smallest edit distance but with edit cost weighed differently, e.g. č to cz cost only 0.2 LD, th to d costs 0.4 LD and p to k costs 1.2 LD? By looking up a reference matrix with all possible replacements. Plus, I am looking to only count an edit for a word once and not again in other words in a list.

Comment: This map (at least the romance part) feels very wrong. I'm a native French speaker, and I live in a Catalan-spoken place. The 2 languages are very close: I can read the news and understand at least the general meaning. The wikipedia page about the language says that it's closer to French than Spanish. Also, a sister language of Catalan is Occitan, and it doesn't appear that way from the map. Also, the Catalan being marked as the closest language from Spanish is plain wrong. Also, French being closer from Italian than Catalan or even Spanish feels wrong as well; etc. etc.

Comment: Would be terrific to have the same map but with last common ancestor present in the graph (on background?), like Proto-Slavic, Latin, Proto-Germanic etc, to visualise degree of divergence from source

Answer (score 13):

As noticed in [this answer](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/3007/1009), Prof. Tyshchenko's work primarily targeted languages spoken in Europe, hence, most of them belong to the Indo-European family; the only exceptions being Basque, Finnish, Estonian, and Hungarian (labelled as Madyarska). Even Celtic languages form a mini-group of four.

[image: Linguistic Distances measured]
<sub>[Image courtesy of](https://alternativetransport.wordpress.com/2015/05/04/how-much-does-language-change-when-it-travels/). I apologize the's no English version of the map with numbers.</sub>

Although I didn't find any direct mention why it does not cover other language families (LF), I think, we may assume that Linguistic Distances (LD) of languages belonging to different LF may be too hard to measure. This is probably caused by too different linguistic tools (mind the vowels, consonants, lexical tones, intonation patterns, and also a whole set of syntactic tools).

If you check the Wikipedia article on [mutually intelligible languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_intelligibility#List_of_mutually_intelligible_languages), you may notice that most language pairs having short LD do belong the same LF.

Also, note that Prof. Tyshchenko's work [(link; sorry for it's in Ukrainian only)](http://linguist.univ.kiev.ua/museum/book/index.html) is not an independent research. Instead, it's rather a result of long hard work of a big group of linguists who elaborated various methodologies of how to measure the LD. And it resulted only [a list of measured LD](https://alternativetransport.wordpress.com/2015/05/04/how-much-does-language-change-when-it-travels/) between the languages spoken in Europe.

---

So I think that the suggested methodology can't be automatically applied to all world's languages, hence there's probably no *worldwide* map you're asking for.

Comment: Yeah, you would probably need people with an in depth knowledge of each language group to do the research. Since these researchers knew Indo-European languages, they were equipped to work on that. I agree that it's unlikely that something like this exists for worldwide.

Comment: I would also glad to see further elaboration of this work. If such a research about worldwide list of languages appear sometime, I would also be very curious to look at it (and stand corrected with my current assumption).

Comment: Yes, it would be very cool if it existed. I'm sure it could be feasible to create it if the right researchers and experts got together.

Comment: So does Tyshchenko's article really talk about 'linguistic distance'? Or about 'lexical distance'?

Comment: @GastonÜmlaut, I think, it's about Linguistic Distance, since it's a property of a pair of Languages. Lexical Distance seems to be a property of a pair of Lexemes.

Comment: Ok, but every other source I've looked at that discusses the Tyschenko article (not sure if any of them were able to read the original) uses the term 'lexical distance'. And it does seem that Tyschenkm's work is based on a comparison of lexical inventories, so there's no morphology, syntax etc. Sometimes this is called 'lexical similarity'.

Comment: While I doubt that you could meaningfully construct a map for all worldwide languages, I would be fascinated to see a similar chart covering all the Indo-European languages. It's a pity those charts don't show any Indic languages because they are equally fascinating.

Comment: It's obvious that we need a new classification for Slavic languages, Instead of a classical one, where Serbo-Croatian is in the Southern group just because it's geographically at the South (science, yeah?) and where Central ones are in Eastern group just because Russian diverged later from the Center (politics, yeah?). It seems that based on this calculation slavic languages classification should look the following way:

Comment: * slavic
    * central (Ruthenian †)
        * north-central (Belarusan)
        * south-central (Ukrainian)
    * western
        * north-western (Polish)
        * central-western (Czech-Slovak)
        * south-western (Serbo-Croatian)
    * southern (Church Slavonic †)
        * southern (Bulgarian)
    * eastern (Muscovite †)
        * central-eastern (Central Russian)
        * south-eastern (Southern  Russian)
    * northern (Novgorodian †)
        * assimilated into north-eastern (Northern Russian)

Answer (score 5):

There is very nice [language similarity chart](https://www.ezglot.com/language-similarity-matrix.html), almost one hundred languages compared..

Comment: I can't find info what kind of measure that table is using. Do you know?

Comment: @glicerico The measure is absurd, it just checks if the words are written the same way in different languages. So, if you write your language in a different orthography, this new language will not match at all against the original one. The values are mostly non-sensical. For example, French (my native language) is supposed to be closer to English (15) than Italian (7), Spanish (11), Catalan (9) or Occitan (7), I assume due to loan words, which is beyond ridiculous.

Answer (score 1):

This lexical map deals mostly with European languages. Most of them are of Indo-European family, but some belong to  the other families like Hungarian, Finnish and Estonian from the Uralic language families. Also, there was the site in the Internet where there was shown some variant of this distance with including several languages from Asian continent like Tajik and Persian. But now it is probably disappeared.

I have my own hypothesis concerning the methods of the lexical comparisons in the map.

It was correctly said by some commentators here that in these lexical distances by prof. Tyshchenko there were not just included completely alien-root words but also
"false fiends of translator", ( because it is impossible to calculate false friends in the Swadesh list as common vocabulary and cognates). There are required exact correspondences in meaning with English concepts of the list.

But it is also possible that there were also used 2 kinds of partial cognates  of the same meaning as  in their counterparts from the other language.

The proof may be here in the publication Правда про походження української мови by prof. Tyshchenko - https://archive.org/details/tishenko/page/n33/mode/2up
The pairs of the words from this fragment of the Slavic Swadesh list (and they are called by prof. Tyshchenko as "innovations".

Here on the page 54 of the printed text (and page 34 in this "slide show" or "video"):

So these two kinds in my opinion may be these:

1. Those which have indirect origin from  one words-ancestor and of ancestral ( not modern) language. Here are coloured as the "innovations" Russian - Ukrainian pairs женщина - жінка (woman) and тяжелый (which is coloured in brown) - тяжкий (hard, heavy). The Ukrainian важкий is complete non-cognate which is occasionaly and grammaticaly alike to Russian and Ukrainian тяжкий.
2. Those, which have direct origin, but have so-called "irregular" sound changes in their roots. The examples are these coloured innovations  of the fragment ( table) on page 54 like Russian - Ukrainian pairs он - він (he) and ладонь - долоня (palm).

The partial cognates which belongs to opposition "general - diminutive" or which have the irregular sound changes just in affixes here are not coloured in any colour as "innovations". Examples are Belarusian жонка (wife), Ukrainian жінка (these two are complete cognates between each other) and Russian жена (it is partial cognate of the same meaning for these two).

Therefore, in other language pairs the comparison probably might realized by this criteria (Spanish "tortuga" (turtle) and Italian "tartaruga" are not complete and direct cognates).  So, it may make difference betwen the data from the present lexical distances map and the other lexical distances calculations.

Additionally, it is necessary to define the criteria, according to which these the  other distances were made. So, there is question whether they are really made according to the division on "cognates - non-cognates" (root-similarity and etymological criteria) or just according to the Normalized Levenshtein distance data.

Also, the Tyshchenko's analysis seems to be in the publication as some kind of "synonymic", while many linguistic made some kinds of analysis without synonyms.

If the map probably may say something about genealogical closeness and subgroup division, it probably cannot say a lot about the intelligibility measurement. Unlike historical linguistics, the different branches of the linguistics which is related to the intelligibility studies (Receptive multilingualism, etc.( will mostly treat these lexical items like the kinds of cognates. And it will use the  Normalized Levenshtein  distance for their intelligibility percentage prediction.

It is important to know that even some pure cognates from some languages may be more differently spelt or pronounced between each other than some partial cognates (sometimes it is true even
for Russian-Ukrainian complete non-cognates pairs, like Запад -Захід (West).

Still, partial cognates (and they are defined as non-cognates or lexical distance by many historical linguists), are the words with  mostly big percent of sound or letter changes. Their intelligibility is complicated (sometimes they may not intelligible at all). It is especially true when they are out of context.

But even in context their intelligibility may be also limited, despite it is better than complete non-cognates, false friends or partial cognates with the different meaning like English "love" and Dutch "belofte" (promise).