# Relative Language Distances

Tags: english, historical-linguistics, french

Could someone compare the distance between Modern French and Middle French to Modern English and Middle English. In general which of these languages has diverged more over time?

Comment: There are many different methodologies for such calculation. Also, I'm afraid there's no comprehensive work for historic languages/dialects. For modern/existing ones, see [here](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/3006/1009) and [here](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/17400/1009).

Comment: I am talking more about the distance between stages of the languages themselves. ie Is it easier for a modern Briton to read XV century English literature or for a French person to read XV century French literature?

Comment: So pronunciation or written?

Give me a text in Middle English and the same one in Modern English, and give me a similar text in Middle French and the same in Modern French and I can try to answer for written language.