# Are there any statistic how similar are any two languages?

Tags: grammar, machine-translation

Are there any statistics on how similar any two languages are?
For a whole language (lexical and structural) or maybe just a comparison of two dictionaries (vocabulary)?

Comment: Largely related: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/3006/1009

Comment: The problem is that "similar" is not well-defined. There are methods of comparing phonologies and morphosyntactic features, but "similarity" is perceptual, and not something that can be measured exactly unless it's given an operational definition.